# Change one file name of 2 un identical files with different extensions

Tags: file

I have 2 file names where one of the is the master from whom I am going to pick the name from to change the second file.
File1 = Research.doc
File2 = Laboratory.xls

In this case File 1 is the leader so I want to pick the name of that file and change it for the file2, so the results of this operation should be

File1 = Reserach.doc  <<<<=== Keep name no changes just to take name
File2 = Research.xls  <<== file 2 change name like the file one and keep same extension just the file name only.

Thanks to all in advance for the input

Code:

```
Option Explicit 
Dim strPath
Dim FSO
Dim FLD
Dim fil
Dim strOldName1
Dim strOldName2
Dim strNewName1
Dim strNewName2
Dim strFileParts
Dim strAccount1
Dim strAccount2
Dim intAccount strPath = "C:\JPMSMB15"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each fil in FLD.Files
    strOldName1 = fil.Path
    strOldName2 = fil.Path

    If InStr(strOldName1, "") > 1 Then
        intAccount = intAccount + 0
        strAccount1 = CStr(intAccount)
        strAccount1 = Right(strAccount, 3)
        strAccount2 = CStr(intAccount)
        strAccount2 = Right(strAccount, 3)
        strFileParts = Split(strOldName1, "")
        strNewName1 = strFileParts(0) & strAccount & ".xls"
        strNewName2 = strFileParts(0) & StrAccount & ".doc"
        FSO.MoveFile strNewName1, strNewName2 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This needs more information.  Are you trying to write a program to do this?

Comment: Yes  I need a VBS scritp or a batch file to do it. either or will work, thanks you so much for asking

Comment: Please update your question above and include the code your are having trouble with.  This site is not to do all of the work for you, sorry.

Comment: You should also add tags such as vbscript to attract the appropriate users to troubleshoot your issues.

Comment: Where you can post your script since it is very long for the comment, would you guide me please I have it but it does not go due to too many charracters